# How to replace body text in MIME message?

Tags: python, mime, multipart

I am trying to send an automated email to various users with the lake that they are subscribed to changing:

```py
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = email  # Sender
message['Subject'] = "Algae Bloom Alert\n"  # Subject

for user in subscriber_dict:
    sms_gateway = subscriber_dict[user]['email']
    message['To'] = subscriber_dict[user]['email']
    body = (
        f"This is an algae alert for Lake {subscriber_dict[user]['lake']}.\n\n"
        f"Sent at {sent_time_date} {sent_time_time}"
    )
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))  # Attaching body to email
    sms = message.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, sms_gateway, sms)
        
    # Reset body here ideally

    print(f"Email sent at {formatted_time}")
```

However, when the emails are sent, each successive email contains the contents from the emails prior to it. Does anyone know how I can reset the body so that I am not attaching to the previous bodies but rather writing new ones?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edit three times. How are you constructing `message` in the first place?

Comment: `message.attach` is probably attaching new text onto the back of the emails sent previously.

Comment: Correct, `message.attach` is just adding on the new text. I am trying to figure out a way to "reset" the text if you will at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Righto - there's no need to keep digging back into `subscriber_dict`. Instead of:

```py
for user in subscriber_dict:
    sms_gateway = subscriber_dict[user]['email']
```

You can do:

```py
for user in subscriber_dict.values():
    sms_gateway = user['email']
```

Your `for` loop is reusing the same `message`. It should probably create a new one on each loop:

```py
FROM_ADDR = "jake@lakefacts.gov.au"

for user in subscriber_dict.values():
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = FROM_ADDR
    message['To'] = user['email']
    message['Subject'] = "Algae Bloom Alert\n"
    body = (
        f"This is an algae alert for Lake {user['lake']}.\n\n"
        f"Sent at {sent_time_date} {sent_time_time}"
    )
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    sms_gateway = user['email']
    sms = message.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, sms_gateway, sms)
    print(f"Email sent at {formatted_time}")
```

Comment: `email` is just a variable name for the email address (example@gmail.com). Thanks for the pointer on the for loop. And yes, a new message should be sent each time (the Lake is being updated depending on what lake a user is subscribed to)

Comment: @Jake S I've updated my answer per your comments - however this is a bit of an informed speculation on my part!

Comment: There is no need to create a multipart if the message only contains a single part. The legacy API for this was `MIMEText` but you should avoid the old API for any new code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse the same `message`. Create a new one inside the loop.

Your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
...

for user in subscriber_dict:
    message = EmailMessage()
    message['From'] = email
    message['Subject'] = "Algae Bloom Alert"  # no \n
    message['To'] = subscriber_dict[user]['email']
    message.set_content(
        f"This is an algae alert for Lake {subscriber_dict[user]['lake']}.\n\n"
        f"Sent at {sent_time_date} {sent_time_time}"
    )
    server.send_message(message)

    print(f"Email sent at {formatted_time}")
```

You might want to avoid calling your sender variable `email` to avoid shadowing the `email` library, although in this example it doesn't really matter.

With `.set_content()` you could actually reuse the same `message` over and over but there is no actual benefit from that, and the problems if you fail to replace some part of an earlier message by mistake could be ugly. (For example, a typo could cause you to send the same message to the same recipient as many times as you have users!)